# How can I call javascript method from my aspx.cs file

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a javascript method which I have to call from the aspx page at the time of page load.

Comment: give a bit more details, and I'm sure we'd be able to help you

Comment: the problem is that i am using updatepanel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript methods are client-side methods, so you can not call them in your server side code.

But if you're looking for a way to call your method at the page load put your method call into script tag and write it in your aspx page :

```
<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    myMethod();
  </script>
</body>
```

Or you can register your scripts from code-behind like that :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "myMethod();";

    if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("myPostBackScript"))
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(MyPage),
               "myPostBackScript", script, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to call this js function everytime the page partial postbacks using UpdatePanel?